# How can I listen for a click-and-hold in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to be able to fire an event when a user clicks on a button, then holds that click down for 1000 to 1500 ms.

Is there jQuery core functionality or a plugin that already enables this?

Should I roll my own? Where should I start?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Long Press in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript)

Comment: How about 'taphold' ??

Answer (score 182, accepted):

```
var timeoutId = 0;

$('#myElement').on('mousedown', function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
}).on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

**Edit**: correction per AndyE...thanks!

**Edit 2**: using bind now for two events with same handler per gnarf

Comment: Update is better, but you might consider clearing the interval in a `mouseleave` handler too.

Comment: You could use the same function for mouseup/mouseleave: `.bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {`

Comment: @gnarf Good point! I've edited it to include your suggestion.

Comment: Nice stuff!  Implemented within jQuery Mobile without any issues.

Comment: @treeface Slick, but I'm confused where the payload would go.  Should the implementation-specific handler be called in the mouseup event?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone no, the logic goes in "myFunction", an anonymous function, the first parameter of setTimeout.

(I know, it's an old comment, but if someone see this and has the same question...)

Comment: anyone know how i can get this to work on iOS devices for elements that are not <a> or <button>, say a <div>? I can only get click events working with onclick="" html attribute, no pointer or mouse events.

Answer (score 13):

Aircoded (but tested on [this fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/gnarf/pZ6BM/))

```
(function($) {
    function startTrigger(e) {
        var $elem = $(this);
        $elem.data('mouseheld_timeout', setTimeout(function() {
            $elem.trigger('mouseheld');
        }, e.data));
    }

    function stopTrigger() {
        var $elem = $(this);
        clearTimeout($elem.data('mouseheld_timeout'));
    }


    var mouseheld = $.event.special.mouseheld = {
        setup: function(data) {
            // the first binding of a mouseheld event on an element will trigger this
            // lets bind our event handlers
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.bind('mousedown', +data || mouseheld.time, startTrigger);
            $this.bind('mouseleave mouseup', stopTrigger);
        },
        teardown: function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.unbind('mousedown', startTrigger);
            $this.unbind('mouseleave mouseup', stopTrigger);
        },
        time: 750 // default to 750ms
    };
})(jQuery);

// usage
$("div").bind('mouseheld', function(e) {
    console.log('Held', e);
})
```

Comment: how to select the text with different color when we tap and hold on the device

Answer (score 9):

I made a simple JQuery plugin for this if anyone is interested.

http://plugins.jquery.com/pressAndHold/

Comment: Nice one. Was able to modify this to detect that an object had been dragged so as to remove a message telling the user to drag the object.

Comment: FANTASTIC plugin. Dropped in to my project and bam, works.

Comment: Your plugin wasn't written for Bootstrap, but works VERY nicely with it! No extra CSS or messing around. Just works. Kudos.

Answer (score 5):

Presumably you could kick off a `setTimeout` call in `mousedown`, and then cancel it in `mouseup` (if `mouseup` happens before your timeout completes).

However, looks like there is a plugin: [longclick](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/longclick).

Answer (score 2):

```
    var _timeoutId = 0;

    var _startHoldEvent = function(e) {
      _timeoutId = setInterval(function() {
         myFunction.call(e.target);
      }, 1000);
    };

    var _stopHoldEvent = function() {
      clearInterval(_timeoutId );
    };

    $('#myElement').on('mousedown', _startHoldEvent).on('mouseup mouseleave', _stopHoldEvent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my current implementation:

```
$.liveClickHold = function(selector, fn) {

    $(selector).live("mousedown", function(evt) {

        var $this = $(this).data("mousedown", true);

        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($this.data("mousedown") === true) {
                fn(evt);
            }
        }, 500);

    });

    $(selector).live("mouseup", function(evt) {
        $(this).data("mousedown", false);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code to make it easy

```js
//Add custom event listener
$(':root').on('mousedown', '*', function() {
    var el = $(this),
        events = $._data(this, 'events');
    if (events && events.clickHold) {
        el.data(
            'clickHoldTimer',
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    el.trigger('clickHold')
                },
                el.data('clickHoldTimeout')
            )
        );
    }
}).on('mouseup mouseleave mousemove', '*', function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('clickHoldTimer'));
});

//Attach it to the element
$('#HoldListener').data('clickHoldTimeout', 2000); //Time to hold
$('#HoldListener').on('clickHold', function() {
    console.log('Worked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" id="HoldListener">
```

[See on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kezzyhko/2ajhj0cn/15/)

Now you need just to set the time of holding and add `clickHold` event on your element