# Jquery auto increment css property on mouse button press and hold

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

Im struggling to create a functionality which keeps on incrementing css property of an element when someone presses and 'holds' a button.

something like this:

```
var timeoutId = 0;

$('#left').mousedown(function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});

function myFunction() {
 var left = parseInt($("#menuElem").css('left')) + 10;
 $("#menuElem").animate({
    'left' : left + 'px'
 });

}
```

I want that myFunction to be repeated again and again until mouseup or mouseleave event is fired.

cheers

Comment: what are you struggling on exactly see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4080508/1114171) for detecting click->hold-down then just check out `.css()`

Comment: apologies for not being clear.. updated my question with the link you provided -cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828613/check-if-a-key-is-down) you can't detect the current up or down state of a key, only monitor the respective events.

So you'd need something like this i guess

```
var mouseIsDown = false;

$('#button').mousedown(function(){
    mouseIsDown = true;
    incrementValue;
});

$('#button').mouseup(function(){
    mouseIsDown = false;
});
```

Then have that function be all like:

```
function incrementValue() {
    whatever++;
    if(mouseIsDown){
        setTimeout("incrementValue()", 20);
    }
}
```

On mouse down, the `mouseIsDown` var gets set to true, and it starts a loop that continues to increment (at whatever interval you set the time parameter to in `setTimeout()`) until `mouseIsDown` is false, which happens on mouseup.

Comment: hello, ive implemented your code -for some reasons it doesent repeat the incrementValue() function, firebug says incrementValue() is not defined on line 'setTimeout("incrementValue()", 20);' any ideas? -cheers.

Comment: Remove the quotes maybe? I haven't tested this, just threw it together to demo the idea, and point you in the right direction.