# Performing action repetitively on a click

Tags: jquery, click

i am not sure how to put this in words,so kindly bear with me .

I have a virtual keypad. In it there is a "backspace" button(div) that deletes a character on each click .
i want it to be more realistic . so the question is "How do i delete multiple characters if the user is pressing the mouse down (i.e the mouse is pressed continously and the user hasn't lift his finger off the mouse )"

```
<div class="dialpadnumbers">1</div>
<div class="dialpadnumbers">2</div>
<div class="dialpadnumbers">3</div>
<div class="dialpadnumbers">4</div>
<div class="dialpadnumbers">5</div>
<div class="dialpadnumbers">6</div>
<div class="dialpadnumbers">7</div>
<div class="dialpadnumbers">8</div>
<div class="dialpadnumbers">9</div>
<div class="dialpadnumbers">0</div>
<div id="dialpadbackspace" class="dialpadnumbers">Backspace</div>
<div id="dialpadcall" class="dialpadnumbers">CALL</div>

/*also the jquery for it(the one ive been using till now is),caret is the fn          
for setting caret position*/
$("#dialpadbackspace").click(function() {
    $('#dialpadentry').focus();
    var init = $("#dialpadentry").val();
    var start = $("#dialpadentry")[0].selectionStart;
    var stop = $("#dialpadentry")[0].selectionEnd;
    if (start == stop) {
        var substr = init.substring(0, start);
        var newsubstr = init.substring(0, start - 1);
        var finale = init.replace(substr, newsubstr);
        $("#dialpadentry").val(finale);
        $('#dialpadentry').caret(start - 1);
    } else {
        var substr = init.substring(start, stop);
        var finale = init.replace(substr, '');
        $("#dialpadentry").val(finale);
        $('#dialpadentry').caret(start);
    }
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080497/jquery-detecting-click-and-hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically on mousedown start a interval which calls a function every x milliseconds that removes a character from the dial. You already got two excellent answers, so I will just post a quick jsfiddle I did.

http://jsfiddle.net/EB29c/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).  Bind the `mousedown` event to `setInterval`, store the ID somewhere, and the `mouseup` event to `clearInterval`.

Be sure to cover edge cases.  For example, if the user clicks your backspace, then drags the mouse away without lifting the mouse button.  `onMouseOut` will need to be bound to `clearInterval`.  There may be other edge cases as well.

Comment: Thanx mwcz and Manse UK . @Mmwcz ill try it out and get back!!cheers

Comment: See a quick fiddle I've done to confirm @mwcz's answer: http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/SDM55/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function () {
    var doBackspace;
    $("#dialpadbackspace").mousedown(function(e) {
        doBackspace = setInterval('$("#dialpadentry").val($("#dialpadentry").val().substr(0, $("#dialpadentry").val().length-1));',100);
    });
    $("#dialpadbackspace").mouseup(function(e) {
        clearInterval(doBackspace);
    });
})();
```

Comment: you would need to modify this a bit to get it to work with edge cases like @mwcz suggests