# Return false; When mouse hold(click) in x seconds

Tags: jquery, click, mousedown

My code is...

```
var timer;
var func = function () {
        $("body").append("1");
};

$(document).on('mousedown' , 'a' , function(e){
        timer = setTimeout(func, 1000);
}).on('mouseup mouseleave' , 'a' , function(e){
        clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Everything working. But when I set this function to some link like `<a href="http://google.com">text</a>`

I need to set `return false;` (not redirect to the url or another `onclick()` functions)

Where `return false;` can I set in ? Or another solution ?

**PS : And I will my link will work normally when click by normal clicking**

**Playground :** http://jsbin.com/iwilop/1/edit

---

[How can I listen for a click-and-hold in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080497/jquery-detecting-click-and-hold)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `click` handler and, if your `func` was called, prevent the default action of the click. Here I'm using `timer` as a flag:

```
var timer = 0;
var func = function () {
  $("body").append("1");
  timer = 0;
};

$(document).on('mousedown' , 'a' , function(e){
  timer = setTimeout(func, 1000);
}).on('mouseup mouseleave' , 'a' , function(e){
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}).on('click', 'a', function() {
  if (!timer) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

[Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/iwilop/9/edit)

Comment: for example in my `func` function ?

Comment: wouldn't `return false` in the `mousup` suffice?

Comment: @l2aelba: No, you're trying to prevent the click, right? So prevent it on the link.

Comment: Yes , But I will can click and redirect to the url when click normally too

Comment: @l2aelba: **sigh** You didn't *say* that. That changes things markedly.

Comment: sorry man... edited my question : `PS : And I will my link will work normally when click by normal clicking`

Answer (score 0):

You need a `click` handler (you don't actually need to call return false unless there are other handlers that could also fire):

```
$(document).on('mousedown' , 'a' , function(e){
        timer = setTimeout(func, 1000);
}).on('mouseup mouseleave' , 'a' , function(e){
        clearTimeout(timer);
}).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        return false;
});
```

Bear in mind that the above will affect all links on the page - you may need to qualify the `a` selector to be more specific (e.g. `a.blah`).

**Edit:** in light of your revised question, I have nothing to offer over and above [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15110051/17602). The only thing I'd say is to watch out for global variables - you might want to wrap the whole thing in an [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) or similar.

Comment: edited my question : `PS : And I will my link will work normally when click by normal clicking`