# Button function if the button is pressed for 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to execute a button function only if the user pressed/clicked on the button for 10 seconds.

the normal button function is:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

so is there any way to count the seconds from the moment the user pressed on the button and KEPT pressing, (a continuous pressing without clicking not tapping), and when the seconds hits 10, the function will execute?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4080508/3130094

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need timers, set one when the mouse is held down, clear it when the mouse is released.

```
$( "#target" ).on({
    mousedown: function() {
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
              foo();
        }, 10000));
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/grwjdy0u/)

Comment: so the foo(); is my function and this will execute if I keep pressing the button for 3 seconds?

Comment: @user3806613 - exactly !

Comment: nice one... i will accept this as the answer in 5 minutes...

Comment: 60.000 is 60 seconds, because 1000 is 1 second. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use mousedown and mouse up instead of click event ,

```
var timeOut = 0;
$("#target").mousedown(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Handler for .click() called.");
    }, 10000);
});
$(document).mouseup(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    console.log("stop");
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yx89w7ea/)**

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery LongPress plugin will handle this for you.

```
https://github.com/vaidik/jquery-longpress
```

You can set the delay parameter before your function executes.

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
var threshold = 10000, timeOne, timeTwo;
$('#t10').mousedown(function(){
    timeOne = new Date();
}).mouseup(function(){
    timeTwo = new Date();
    if(timeTwo - timeOne >= threshold){
        alert('Do what you want');
        timeOne = 0;
    }else{
        console.log('Released early');
    }
});
```

HTMl

```
<button  id="t10">XX</button>
```

Fiddle
**http://jsfiddle.net/5z94y2z5/**

Answer (score 0):

you needs to use mousedown and mouseup events

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/
http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/

```js
var pressedtensecondos = false;
var timer = null;

$( "#target" ).mousedown(function() {
  timer = setTimeout(function() { pressedtensecondos = true; }, 10000);
});

$( "#target" ).mouseup(function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  
  if(pressedtensecondos)
    alert('ten seconds');

  pressedtensecondos = false;
});
```