# Javascript focus range element slider

Tags: javascript, html

i am working on a custom video player design for smartphones, now i want to implement a function that when i am holding the volume icon with my finger then then a container with a range element expands. How can i change the focus now to the range element that i can change immediately the range value.

`inputelm.focus() dont work the way i want.`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j484e6hh/) (the second image is the volume image, dont wanna uplaod all icons)

Comment: Can you be more clear??

Comment: if i hold down my finger on the volume icon the container expends with the rage element. Now i want to change the range elements value by just move the finger left and right, but it dont work at the moment because i dont know how to change the focus to the range element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080497/how-can-i-listen-for-a-click-and-hold-in-jquery
On every settimeout callback, you may expand the cointainer with a range element.

Comment: @user2975123 i wanna change the range of the range element not the size of the container.

Comment: In that case you have to change the value of the range input inside the class "volumeslider_container" from every timeout callback