# Click and hold onto a selected div to hide?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch

I have the following code that will hide an element when it is clicked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> 

<script> 
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){   

$("p").on("taphold",function(){
        $(this).hide();   
});                        

}); 

</script> 
</head>
```

## The taphold Event

If you tap and hold me for one second, I will disappear.

Tap and hold me!

Tap and hold me too!

## Footer Text

What I would like to do is change the `<p>` to `<div>` elements and click on different divs to hide them:

```html
<div id='d1'>If you tap and hold me for one second, I will disappear.</div>
<div id='p4'>Tap and hold me!</div>
<div id='g7'>Tap and hold me too!</div>
```

Comment: You can refer to this SO answer for your desired output. [SOAnswer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080497/how-can-i-listen-for-a-click-and-hold-in-jquery)

Comment: Not quite.  This listens to specific DIVs, but what if I have 60 of them?

Comment: Why you need convert `p` to `div` ?

Comment: The example I posted uses p, I want to use div instead because I have a lot of divs where I would to use click-hold to hide.  I already use doubleclick and click for other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually understand. Do you want to click on `div` instead of `p`

Then just change the `p` in jquery to `div`

```
<div id='d1' class="clickme">If you tap and hold me for one second, I will disappear.</div>
<div id='p4' class="clickme">Tap and hold me!</div>
<div id='g7' class="clickme">Tap and hold me too!</div>
<script> 
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){   

$(".clickme").on("taphold",function(){

  var id  = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#"+id).hide();   
});                        

}); 

</script>
```

Comment: In the original code it uses <P>, but now I actually want to click on DIVs with IDs.  I've tried your version before posting this and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Try this. Now it gets it's id and hides that `div` that matches with that `id`

Comment: It still doesn't work for me.  What it does is that it hides all the divs, not the one that I clicked.

Comment: I tried this: 

    $(document).on("taphold",function(){
    alert($(this).innerHTML);
    });  

Just to see the content of what I clicked.  It alerts the element but not the content.

Comment: Add a class name. and try getting `div` through that class and then get the `id` and hide that `div`

Comment: That's a lot better.  Is there a way to run this code without "$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){ "?

Comment: I don't know the dept of it but I guess this code is working fine. Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks again and yes this is the best answer.  I would prefer to reference the DIV id instead of the class but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some tips from Ali Rasheed,

the changes in code are as followed:

```
<div id='d1'>If you tap and hold me for one second, I will disappear.</div>
<div id='p4'>Tap and hold me!</div>
<div id='g7'>Tap and hold me too!</div>

$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){   

$("p").on("taphold",function(){
        $(this).hide();   
});
```

to:

```
<div id='d1' class="clickme">If you tap and hold me for one second, I will disappear.</div>
<div id='p4' class="clickme">Tap and hold me!</div>
<div id='g7' class="clickme">Tap and hold me too!</div>

$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){   

$(".clickme").on("taphold",function(){

  var id  = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#"+id).hide();   
});
```

Most importantly, this will NOT work without the following added to your code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

You need jquery.mobile otherwise tap-hold will not work at all.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Of course you need `cdn` to make jquery work! That is the initial step you have to take!

Comment: And beneath those voting UP and DOWN buttons there is a Green tick button. Please approve answer if my code worked for you

Comment: Done, I didn't know that I needed jquery.mobile to do this as I've been trying to do it without jquery without success.