# Simulate click and hold onmouseover javascript

Tags: javascript, accessibility, uiaccessibility

Hello I'm working with eye tracker which, unfortunately can't simulate a mouse click. Is possible to simulate click and hold onmouserover event? I'm using this code to set DIV moveable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#otazka" ).draggable({ containment: "#obsah" });
}); 
</script>

<div id="obsah">
    <div id="otazka">
        <p>Click and drag</p>
    </div>           
</div>
```

I need the function to call onmouserover event to simulate click and hold for example 5 sec and after release, then delay so, the user can get the cursor off of that div to prevent repeatedly call of onmouserover event. Sorry for my english and thanks for answers.

Comment: Where is the end of your `script` ? And if you want a librairy to drag and drop, look this maybe : https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080497/how-can-i-listen-for-a-click-and-hold-in-jquery

Comment: @Frank This one asks for how to produce them instead of how to listen for them.