# Click and Long Click in iOS and PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, click

Is there any way to differentiate between click and long click in html while using Phonegap? I have used js plugins for long tap/click and they are working good but i have to call different functions on both gestures but long click also executes the click function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to catch "touch begin" and "touch end" event, start a timer, if timer if touch ends before timer fires it is a short touch and if timer fires its a long one.

Comment: you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript

Comment: Ok. now i have the idea that only timers would help me in this case. I really appreciate your help :)