# How to achieve longclick in kendo ui listview

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am doing a mobile application in kendo UI. When clicking on the item in the listview its redirecting to some page. My requirement is that for long click also it should redirect to some page.

How can i make it possible in mobile using kendo ui?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post your code if possible on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/general-discussions/raising-touch-events-in-mobile-using-kendo-ui-web.aspx) from Kendo UI forums (no native OS events), you could look at **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript)** about **Long Press** just down the road in SO.

Basically start experimenting with JavaScript events and timers.

As far as I know, JQuery Mobile events (taphold) and plugins are not an option as they would be competing with Kendo UI for page control, but you might get some ideas for your implementation.