# jquery "click" vs "hold" a hyperlink

Tags: php, jquery

I am dealing with a menu action in a php website in tablet. Of course, if a menu has some hyperlinks, while clicking it, the website will be redirected to another url.

This time, I have to achieve, when "clicking" this hyperlink for less than 1 sec, only the sub-menu will go out, and when "clicking" and "holding" this hyperlink for more than 1 sec, then it really redirects to another url.

so, my idea is:-

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu').click(function(){
        if (holding is less than 1000ms){
            //it does nothing;
        }else if (holding is more than 1000ms){
            //it executes the hyperlink;
        }
    })
})
```

In terms of jquery, how can I work it out?

Comment: it is `mousedown` / `mouseup` event, or `mousedown` + `setTimeout`

Comment: Are you sure this method will be user friendly?

Comment: mousedown -> create date object -> mouseup -> compare date object against current time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Long Press in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `setTimeout()`

```
var tOut;
$('.menu').on('mousedown', function () {
    console.log("this is less than one second");
    tOut = setTimeout(function () {
        alert("Holded more than one second");
    }, 1000);
});
$('.menu').on('mouseup', function () {
    clearTimeout(tOut);
});
```