# Cleanest way to achieve <abbr>-type functionality on touch-screens?

Tags: javascript, html

So, "hover" doesn't really exist on touchscreens.  So what's the best option, a bit of javascript to give a small popup with an "x" in the corner to close it down?

I'd rather not have a mass of code to achieve this simple effect.

Answer (score 0):

Hover on touch devices is tricky. One option is to have a "long press" event trigger the tooltip/popup, in which case [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript).

Another, more low-tech option is to add a small icon next to every element that needs a hoverable. When the icon is clicked, the hoverable opens. The benefit to this option is that it's more accessible (providing the icon is not microscopic, of course).

Comment: Why a long-press instead of a normal-press?  What have I missed?

Comment: There's no reason a single click wouldn't work (unless the text is already a link). From my experiences, long-press to show tooltips is more common.

Comment: Long-press seems like a usability issue.  Some people wouldn't realise they had to long-press, and would only short-press, and wouldn't see any effect?

In my case the text isn't also a hyperlink, that would be horribly messy, I'm glad I don't have to deal with that scenario.

Comment: Here's one way of implementing option 2: http://jsfiddle.net/eJNbU/1/. Though as you say, you could also just do a simple click to open the dialog.