# How to recognize long-press gesture in ember-based app?

Tags: android, ember.js, long-press

Now I'm developing mobile app based on html5 and phoneGap.The JS famework is ember.The specification of the app requires to respond to long-press gesture. But the long-press event isn't ember build-in event.

What should I do to recognize the gesture and connect to event handling(controller or route)?

Comment: Do you have some sort of JavaScript library that handles long presses? If so, you could create an Ember view and use that to handle a long press DOM event.

Comment: Here's an SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript) that has a a script.

Comment: Ember can't handle long-press. I use touchStart and touchEnd events to handle the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with `mouseUp` and `mouseDown` but you can use the `touchStart` and `touchEnd` events I'm sure. See [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_event-names)

I setup a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AGeyivo/2/edit?html,css,js,output), but here's the relevant code:

```
var myfunction = function() { 
  alert('held');
}

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  mouseDown: function(e){
   var runLater = Ember.run.later(this, myfunction, 1000);
    this.set('pressed', runLater);
  },

  mouseUp: function (e) { 
    Ember.run.cancel(this.get('pressed'));
  }
})
```

Comment: What should I do If I want to access the attribute of view in "myfunction"? For example, I want to send an event to the relative controller.