# How to click and long press on iPad?

Tags: jquery, ipad, click, touch

I wonder what a click is on an iPad. in my code I use a jQuery click() event and when I tap on the element with click event bound to it, I get the right behavior but when I hold my finger for longer time than a single tap, nothing happens. what is this long press if it is not a click?

Comment: [**Touch Events on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent)

Comment: You should accept the answers if they helped you. The right tick mark next to answers(its turns green when you click it)

Answer (score 1):

if you want long press go this way

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript)

Also Try longclick with this [**plugin**](https://github.com/pisi/Longclick)

```
$(element).longclick(500, function(){
$(element).html("long click works");
});
```