# Long button press on iOS (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

Is it possible to make a button be able to have a long button press on iOS? I have searched all over and not found any solutions for this problem. At first if you long press a button it will try to select it (for copying). Using some CSS, I disabled this, but it still doesn't register a long button press. I think it is because the possibility that you might be scrolling the page that it does not long press in the first place. The purpose of this is that I want the button to disappear on a long press.

Here is a JSFiddle that works on PC, but doesn't on my iPhone (there is a div commented out because it doesn't matter if the long press is on a div or button, I can create an artificial button using a div):
http://jsfiddle.net/ynkLmz5n/3/

Thanks in advance.

```
var MenuToggle = document.getElementsByClassName("hide")[0];
MenuToggle.style["-webkit-user-select"] = "none";
MenuToggle.addEventListener("mousedown", Vanish);
MenuToggle.addEventListener("mouseup", VanishClear);
var timer;
function Vanish() {
    longpress = false;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        MenuToggle.style.display = "none";
    }, 1000);
}
function VanishClear() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript has what you asked but seems noone cared to test that on iOS it seems. Maybe you can try convert https://github.com/pisi/Longclick into vanilla JS like you are using, looks like that one works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [`touch`](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events) events?

```
var timer

MenuToggle.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    MenuToggle.style.display = 'none'
  }, 1000)
}, false)

MenuToggle.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer)
}, false)
```

Comment: Nope, forgot about them completely. I've used them before, but not for a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `touch` events (touchstart and touchend) in place of mouse events.

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ynkLmz5n/4/

```
MenuToggle.addEventListener("touchstart", Vanish);
MenuToggle.addEventListener("touchend", VanishClear);
```

Also, if you're looking to add touch interaction, I'd recommend hammer.js. It's a great touch library that includes support for things like `Press`)

Project page: http://hammerjs.github.io/

Press event documentation: http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-press/

Comment: Thanks. This worked well. I don't need full touch interaction, just this one element needs it.