# How to implement long-press event using Polymer1.0?

Tags: javascript, events, polymer, polymer-1.0

It seems like long-press event is not part of the Polymer's specifications.

How would you implement that ?

I thought about using a behavior and using `down` and `up` event with some `debounce` tricks to manage such a new event but that means I have to make a custom element to use this behavior and can't for example use it directly on any elements I want like :

```
<div on-long-press="_cheese">...</div>
```

which is not convenient.

Would you have other solutions ?

Comment: You asked this question on the exact day that I was wondering the same :)

Comment: @Andre please join the chat room for talking about it (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81301/polymer)

Comment: Have you tried the `on-hold` or `on-holdpulse` [events](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/touch.html#basic-usage)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to make a custom element for this. This is what [polymer behaviors](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html) are for. They provide a way for different polymer elements to share common behaviors.

As for the actual javascript for implementing the long-press you can get ideas from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript).

Comment: as I said in my question, I know how to implement such an event, and I know that I can use behaviors. I was just wondering if I could get the same effect using other aspect of the framework. like the on-tap attribute which is not one of the specifications of html.

Comment: I am not aware of anything that is documented, but you can try to follow the [Gestures source code](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/standard/gestures.html#L464) in registering your own event in Polymer.Gestures similar to the way `on-tap` is registered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Vaadin gesture for this.

https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-context-menu/blob/master/vaadin-long-touch.html

`<paper-button on-vaadin-long-touch="function"></paper-button>`