# Polymer 1.0 'hold' or 'long-press' gesture event?

Tags: polymer-1.0

On this page https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-gestures it says that polymer-gestures is deprecated. The polymer 1.x gesture events don't include a hold event. Before going to implement my own gesture regognizer based on down, up and a timed task, I would like to know if there are plans to add a 'hold' or 'long press' gesture, or if there is already an implementation that plugs into the gestures system?
Related question: [How to implement long-press event using Polymer1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005504/how-to-implement-long-press-event-using-polymer1-0)

Answer (score 0):

I asked the Polymer team about this recently, and there are no plans to add a long-press in the near term.

However, Vaadin has released this gesture that works well. https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-context-menu/blob/master/vaadin-long-touch.html