# override focus trigger for input box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, inputbox

As you can see with the gif below, trello's list titles are input boxes that get focused onclick, but don't get focused on if you long click. How can this functionality be implemented? I am using react, so no jquery, but vanilla js is fine, thanks

[image: trello input box]

Answer (score 0):

It's long press

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.handleButtonPress = this.handleButtonPress.bind(this)
    this.handleButtonRelease = this.handleButtonRelease.bind(this)
  }
  handleButtonPress () {
    this.buttonPressTimer = setTimeout(() => alert('long press activated'), 1500);
  }

  handleButtonRelease () {
    clearTimeout(this.buttonPressTimer);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div 
          onTouchStart={this.handleButtonPress} 
          onTouchEnd={this.handleButtonRelease} 
          onMouseDown={this.handleButtonPress} 
          onMouseUp={this.handleButtonRelease} 
          onMouseLeave={this.handleButtonRelease}>
        Button
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Original: [react long press event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048957/react-long-press-event)