# Javascript: Long Press for File Dialog

Tags: javascript, file, dialog

Is it possible to use long press for file dialog? For example [Long Press in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript) has an answer to trigger an event in long press. However, this can't be used for triggering file input click in most browsers since it is not considered as a user activation.

```
var pressTimer;

$("a").mouseup(function(){
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
  // Clear timeout
  return false;
}).mousedown(function(){
  // Set timeout
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() 
  {    fileChooser.click() // assume fileChoose is a file input element
       // This is suppressed by most browsers.
  },1000);
  return false; 
});
```

Comment: Worked for me on the latest firefox.  I will say that I wasn't using jQuery for this.  Sometimes you just need the raw, not the wrapped, element.  https://jsfiddle.net/psc4yk76/2/

Comment: Also worked on current Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible.  You'd probably have to develop your own detection for it using the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events.  Calculate the time between the `mousedown` and `mouseup` and decide if the delay was long enough to cause some other action.

https://jsfiddle.net/psc4yk76/2/

```
(function() {
  const longtime = 500;
  const target = document.getElementById('target');
  const input = document.getElementById('input');
  const button = document.getElementById('button');

  var timedown = 0;

  button.onmousedown = () => {
    timedown = new Date().getTime();
  };

  button.onmouseup = () => {
    let timeup = new Date().getTime();
    let insert = document.createElement('div');

    if( (timeup - timedown) < longtime ) {
      insert.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Short!'));
    } else {
      insert.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Long!'));
      input.click();
    }

    target.appendChild(insert);
  }
})()
```