# Long-Press also fires "click" and "mouseup"

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, eventtrigger

I have a table row and I want to have two functions when I click on this. With a long-press I want to select the row (add an ".active_row" class) and with a normal click I want to open the details site for this dataset.

For the long-press detection I use the third party script found [here](https://www.cssscript.com/handle-long-press-tap-event-in-javascript-long-press-js/). With little modifications it works for me and fires the event "long-press" correctly. But the problem now is, if I release the mousebutton the events mouseup and click are fired too...

I compared the event details of the automatic fired after longpress-click and the manual fired click and they are identic. So I can't distinguish it with this.

Any ideas?

The third party script fires the custom long-press event with this after the mousebutton is down for 500ms. it uses the events mousedown and a simple timeout function:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('long-press', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));
```

Comment: Inside onlongpress set a variable e.g. `isLongPress` to `true`. Inside the onlick you can then set the variable to `false` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```js
// listen for long-press events
document.addEventListener('long-press', function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
  e.target.setAttribute('data-long-pressed', true);
});

// listen for long-press events
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if ( e.target.getAttribute('data-long-pressed') ) { 
      e.preventDefault() ;
      e.stopPropagation() ;
      e.target.removeAttribute('data-long-pressed');
  }
  // What you whant here
}, true);


/*!
 * long-press.js
 * Pure JavaScript long-press event
 * https://github.com/john-doherty/long-press
 * @author John Doherty <www.johndoherty.info>
 * @license MIT
 */
!function(t,e){"use strict";function n(){this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("long-press",{bubbles:!0,cancelable:!0})),clearTimeout(o),console&&console.log&&console.log("long-press fired on "+this.outerHTML)}var o=null,s="ontouchstart"in t||navigator.MaxTouchPoints>0||navigator.msMaxTouchPoints>0,u=s?"touchstart":"mousedown",a=s?"touchcancel":"mouseout",i=s?"touchend":"mouseup";"initCustomEvent"in e.createEvent("CustomEvent")&&(t.CustomEvent=function(t,n){n=n||{bubbles:!1,cancelable:!1,detail:void 0};var o=e.createEvent("CustomEvent");return o.initCustomEvent(t,n.bubbles,n.cancelable,n.detail),o},t.CustomEvent.prototype=t.Event.prototype),e.addEventListener(u,function(t){var e=t.target,s=parseInt(e.getAttribute("data-long-press-delay")||"1500",10);o=setTimeout(n.bind(e),s)}),e.addEventListener(i,function(t){clearTimeout(o)}),e.addEventListener(a,function(t){clearTimeout(o)})}(this,document);
```

```css
.dock-item {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: arial;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
}

.selected{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="dock-item" data-long-press-delay="500" href='/' target='_blank'>Press and hold me for .5s</a>
<a class="dock-item" href='/' target='_blank'>Press and hold me for 1.5s</a>
<a class="dock-item" data-long-press-delay="5000" href='/' target='_blank'>Press and hold me for 5s</a>
```

A fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/2q7430sy/ (because click do not work in stackoverflow code snippet)